# When I have headphones in my computer and I unplug them the sound (speakers) does not work

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

Sometimes I leave my headphones in my computer after shutting off my computer, when I come back to it I forget that my headphones are plugged in, which is fine, the strange part is if I unplug them later, I get no sound from my speakers. Anyone have any idea why this might be happening and how to remedy it?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you. Please look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: @Joshua I can't see the full list of your audio device settings, but is the headphone jack sense muted?

Comment: @RolandiXor what do you mean?

Comment: @Joshua it's a setting that you can find in `alsamixer`. Just keep pressing your → button and you will find it.